# What does Sofie Fatale say in Japanese on her cellphone in Volume 1?

Tags: dialogue, kill-bill, translation

In [Kill Bill Vol. 1](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0266697/combined), Just before Sofie Fatale and the rest of the crew are about to enter the Japanese nightclub, there's a flashback in which she's speaking Japanese into her cellphone during the wedding rehearsal fight.

I know it's probably not important for the story, but was always curious: what is she saying?

She starts with `Mushi mushi`, which is all that I recognise.

Comment: @AnkitSharma I think the OP got that. It's the rest he didn't get...

Comment: Conversation is here https://www.youtube.com/watch?feature=player_detailpage&v=GVsla1p83wM#t=69

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I have a coworker that is Japanese and she said this is what Sofie Fatale said during the phone call

"Hi, I'm in the middle of a meeting. Can you call me back a bit later? ...Oh you're with your wife? haha, sure I got it."

Also she mentioned that her Japanese sucks

The call is here, starts at 1:08